# Best way to handle product and supplier relationship

Tags: java, class-diagram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [best way to handle a many to many relationship?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142974/best-way-to-handle-a-many-to-many-relationship)

The relationship between product and supplier is many to many with a new class to be created? Or is it many to 1?